# Translate Floating Action Button on ViewPager scroll

Tags: android, animation, floating-action-button

I have a screen with 3 tabs, a ViewPager below with 3 Fragments and a Floating Action Button in bottom-right corner.

When 1st tab is current tab then I want to show the FAB in bottom-right corner. When 2nd tab is current tab then I want to show the FAB in bottom-centre. When 3rd tab is current tab then I want to hide the FAB.

The translate animation from bottom-right to bottom-centre or vice versa should happen as the view pager scrolls i.e. on the basis of scroll amount.

Below is what I have tried.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            ViewCompat.animate(mFAB)
                    .translationX(-translate)
                    .withLayer()
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                    .start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mTabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Is this the best way to do this? If yes what should be the value of translate variable?

Please help me in implementing this.

For reference you can checkout Android Lollipop Call application. The FAB to show the dialer animates in similar manner. For 1st tab its in bottom-right then for middle tab it comes in the centre. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would be for example like this:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        final int width = mViewPager.getWidth();
        if (position == 0) { // represents transition from page 0 to page 1 (horizontal shift)
            int translationX = (int) ((-(width - mFab.getWidth()) / 2f) * positionOffset);
            mFab.setTranslationX(translationX);
            mFab.setTranslationY(0);
        } else if (position == 1) { // represents transition from page 1 to page 2 (vertical shift)
            int translationY = (int) (mFab.getHeight() * positionOffset);
            mFab.setTranslationY(translationY);
            mFab.setTranslationX(-(width - mFab.getWidth()) / 2f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Bare in mind that `width` parameter should represent the width of the screen (I assumed that the `ViewPager` fills the width of the screen (so I assigned `width = mViewPager.getWidth()`).

You also didnt exactly say in what way you want your `FAB` to be hidden. So I just translated it vertically. You could also use `setScaleX(...)` and `setScaleY(...)`.

***Edit:***

The (step) value of the changed parameter should be calculated using the following method (Let's call it - for future references - `formula 1`):

```
// formula 1
value = targetValue - ((targetValue - initialValue) * (1.0f - offset));
```

where `offset` represents a parameter that changes (within range `[0f; 1f]`). So in your case `offset` is `positionOffset` argument of the `onPageScrolled` method.

Let's analyze the transition between pages 0 and 1 (of your case; `position==0`):

1. You want to move your `FAB` horizontally, so you will be modifying the `translationX` paramenter.
2. `FAB` is anchored at the bottom-right corner (e.g. with `layout_gravity="bottom|right"`)
3. The initial position of the `FAB` is the proper position of your animation for NOT scrolled page 0. Therefore the the `initialValue` of the `translationX` for your animation is `0`

```
initialValue = 0;
```

4. You want to move your `FAB` to the center of the screen. Given the screen width as a variable `width` you can calculate the proper `targetValue` for the `FAB` shift to the center of the screen. It's equal to half of the screen width subtracted by half of the `FAB` width. And since you're starting from the right corner, this value be negative (``)

```
targetValue = -(width - mFab.getWidth()) / 2f;
```

5. Due to the fact that the `initialValue` parameter is `0`, you can simplify the `formula 1` to (will be referenced as `formula 2`):

```
// formula 2
value = targetValue * offset;
```

6. Taking the calculated `targetValue` you end up with this (`formula 2` with calculated `targetValue` and `positionOffset` instead of `offset`):

```
value = (-(width - mFab.getWidth()) / 2f) * positionOffset;
```

Which is exactly what I used to move `FAB` from the initial position (`bottom|right`) to the center of the screen (horizontally). 
I went through a similar process in calculating the desired step value for the `translationY` in the transition between page 1 and 2.

What you need to do is do the same thing for any future steps. Think about `initialValue` and `targetValue` of the animated parameters, insert calculated values into the `formula 1` and see if it works as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, there is one problem. When I go to tab 3 from tab1 then the FAB comes in the center then goes down. Is it possible to send the FAB down from right corner without bringing it in the center?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with just a simple `OnPageChangeListener`. It would have to be much more complex and you would have to synchronize it with the other way you can move through the pages in your `ViewPager` (so for example with buttons-tabs if your `ViewPager` represents a tabbed layout)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please answer my question at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201432/animate-floating-action-button-on-viewpager-scroll

Comment: Why don't you try to understand my code here and figure out the answer to your new question yourself? It's really super, super easy... You just need to spend few minutes on the code.

Comment: I have understood your part and even tried to implement the same in my new question. However, the Tab3 and Tab4 scroll part is kinda tough. I have edited the question. Have a look.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my new question?

Comment: In you code, you are animating the FAB in x-direction only once and in y-direction only once. Suppose on both the swipes I animate the FAB in x-direction then the first animation will animate the view from initial position to new (bottom-center) position, however, the second animation also starts from the initial (bottom-right) position instead of new (bottom-center) position. How can I fix this?

Comment: I editted my answer to explain a bit more the process of figuring out the values that you should use for your animation.