# Animate Floating Action Button on ViewPager scroll

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

I have AppBarLayout, ViewPager below it and a Floating Action Button in one Activity. I want to animate the FAB when the ViewPager is scrolled. Have a look at the below screens.

[image]

When Tab1 is the current tab then the FAB should be in the bottom-right corner. When Tab2 is the current tab then the FAB should be in the bottom-center area. When Tab3 is the current tab then the FAB should move back to bottom-right corner. When Tab4 is the current tab then the FAB should get anchored to ImageView4 and should be in the bottom-right corner of ImageView4.

How can I achieve this? Please help me out.

I need to implement onPageChangeListener on ViewPager and handle the same in onPageScrolled().

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            final int width = mViewPager.getWidth();
            if(position == 0) {
                // Transition from page 0 to page 1 (horizontal shift)
                int translationX = (int) ((-(width - mFab.getWidth()) / 2f) * positionOffset);
                mFab.setTranslationX(translationX);
                mFab.setTranslationY(0);
            } else if(position == 1) {
                // Transition from page 1 to page 2 (horizontal shift)
                int translationX = (int) (((width - mFab.getWidth())) * positionOffset);
                mFab.setTranslationX(translationX);
                mFab.setTranslationY(0);
            } else if(position == 2) {
                // Transition from page 2 to page 3

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

When I go from tab1 to tab2 the FAB in translating correctly, however, in the end it comes back to original position.

How should I animate the FAB in onPageScrolled()?

Comment: Do you really need it to be the same FAB? What if you had one per fragment (so you can pin them to their correct positions), and you could animate them just like Example #4 here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-behavior

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily with coordinate layout. 
First, add Support Design Library in gradle:
    `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

Now lets create a simple layout for our activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your fist layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your second layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

This should work, else, you can play around by putting both layout inside co-orindate layout and show hide the second one.

More details in link :http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html